# Multiple dropdown posted to foreach loop; variables repeating

Tags: php, mysql

I'm asking in regards to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43578118/how-to-parse-an-array-into-variables-php) question. I have 12 dropdowns that I wish to be posted to a separate page so that I can use them in a query.

**Edit:**
The first dropdown has three options: Student, Alumni Faculty. The second has New York, Paris or London. They are in one form and posted to another page.

```
<?php
$selected_options=$_POST;
foreach($selected_options as $key=>$option){
$countValue = count($option);
for($i=0; $i<$countValue; $i++){
    $queryString_start_with_comma .= ",$option[$i]";
}
$queryString_remove_extra_comma= preg_replace("/,/", "", $queryString_start_with_comma, 1);
$query_string_with_and .= " AND $key IN($queryString_remove_extra_comma)"; 
unset($queryString_start);
}
$query_string_second_part_ready = preg_replace("/AND/", "", $query_string_with_and, 1);
$query_string= "SELECT * FROM dummy_table WHERE ".$query_string_second_part_ready;
echo $query_string;
?>
```

**However, when I post my values, it ends up looking like this:
"SELECT * FROM dummy_table WHERE role IN(Student) AND city IN(Student,New York)"** I'd like them to be separate.

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: What do you mean, "I'd like them to be separate"? You'll also need to wrap the WHERE values in quotes. And you're suuuuper open to SQL injections attacks.

Comment: I have 12 dropdowns and only mentioned two: select the role of student, alumni, and faculty, and and select the city they live in. The student value is getting grouped with city. And yes, I will adjust for SQL injections, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out .... I didn't complete the full variable when unsetting the variables. "unset($queryString_start);" should be "unset($queryString_start_with_comma);"

And I will make sure to edit to avoid SQL injections.